# Show Octave plot from shell script

Tags: bash-scripting, octave

If I invoke Octave to plot something, it needs the interactive prompt to stay running and show the plot.

When running from the command line, the `--persist` option will force Octave to keep open after all Octave commands are executed, so I can see and manipulate the plot.

> --persist    Go interactive after --eval or reading from FILE.

However, when I invoke Octave from a non-interactive shell script, it cannot enter interactive mode, does not react to `--persist` command line option, nor the `pause()` command inside Octave scripts.

Is there any way to allow Octave invisibly stay interactive, if invoked from a shell script?

Answer (score 3):

I try to reproduce your problem but it was not possible.
I did this test files `oct.txt`

```
x = -10:.1:10;
y = sin(x).*exp(-abs(x));
plot(x,y)
```

and `go.sh` (and I make it executable with `chmod u+x go.sh`)

```
#!/bin/bash
octave -q --persist oct.txt  # It calls the octave and remain as interactive
echo " Now we continue "     # Here the script continue when you exit from octave
sleep 5                      # Do some stuffs
exit                         # It exits
```

When I run it with `./go.sh` it starts `octave` and when I exit it continues with the script.

---

When I add `pause()` or `pause(10)` to the bottom of `oct.txt` and I call octave with the command `octave -q oct.txt &` it behaves as supposed:

1. the script starts *octave* in background and continues
2. eventually the script ends  leaving alive the octave windows

Unfortunately the windows of *octave* is *frozen* from the `pause` command and not so useful.

---

- GNU bash, version 4.3.11
- GNU Octave, version 3.8.1

Comment: Same here, Hastur's example works exatly as he says. +1 for me.

Comment: Ah I forgot to mention the scripts where non-interactive. Added that. I'm sorry!